# Can I have an indication of ETA for an ALTER statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

PostgreSQL 14 here.

I am currently running an ALTER command on a huge table. It has already been running for 13 hours and it keeps going. It is active. Is there a way I could get an indication of when this should be expected to finish?

Comment: First, look in `pg_stat_activity` for wait events.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the query is "active" and there is a wait_event "DataFileRead" of wait_event_type "IO". But this is not constantly the case. Sometimes the wait_event and wait_even_type is "NULL". But when it is not, it has the values "DataFileRead" and "IO" respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, verify that the `ALTER TABLE` is not blocked:

```
SELECT wait_event_type, wait_event
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state = 'active' AND query LIKE 'ALTER TABLE %';
```

If there is no lock indicated, the statement is actually running.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to follow the progress of an `ALTER TABLE` that rewrites the table. You could look at the old and the new data file and compare the size and make your guesses from that, but the is complicated by the fact that all the indexes are also re-created, so it's hard to know what to compare with that.

You can find out the old data file for the table like this:

```
SELECT d.oid::text || '/' || t.relfilenode AS datafile
FROM pg_database AS d
   CROSS JOIN pg_class AS t
WHERE d.datname = current_database()
  AND t.relname = 'mytable';
```

Similarly, you can find the data files for indexes.

To look at the data files, log into the database machine, change into the data directory, then run

```bash
ls -l base/12345/54321*
```

where `12345/54321` is the output of the above query. That will show you how big your old table or index is.

to find the file that is currently being written, you can look at the file with the latest modification timestamp:

```bash
ls -latr base/12345 | tail -1
```

If that file is `98765.7`, that is the eighth segment of file 98765, so the table/index being written is currently betwee 7 and 8 GB in size.

Sorry, that's the best I can give you.